# Bug in floor function

Tags: python

```
floor(-1e-14 % 2)
Out[1]: 1.0

floor(-1e-16 % 2)
Out[2]: 2.0
```

I understand that `-1e-16` may be too close from `0`, but in no way the result of floor after a `% 2` operation should be 2 (0 or 1)!

Comment: Seems more like an issue with the `%` operator than a bug in `floor`.

Comment: According to my Python 3.3.1, `-1e-16 % 2` is `2`

Comment: Presumably `%2` moves `-1e-16` to the positive range (essentially adding `2`), and consequently the number gets rounded and you get a weird result. Oh well. Floating points.

Comment: let the downvotes roll! need more downvotes!  a new user asking a good question! quick, everyone! down down !

Comment: Before claiming a bug in `floor()`, you should have looked at what you input to `floor()`

Answer (score 6):

It is not a bug in floor.Check the result of `%`

```
In [61]: -1e-16 % 2
Out[61]: 2.0

In [62]: -1e-14 % 2
Out[62]: 1.99999999999999
```

You may read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) to know more on why `%` is behaving so.

The [decimal](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) module provides support for decimal floating point arithmetic. It offers several advantages over the foat datatype. So for precise math on floating point values

**sys.float_info**

For detailed information about float type one may use `sys.flaot_info`.

`sys.float_info.dig` shows  maximum number of decimal digits that can be faithfully represented in a float; For calculations that includes values with more digits you may not expect accurate results with the given precision

This is what i have got

```
In [217]: import sys

In [218]: sys.float_info.dig
Out[218]: 15
```

Comment: I don't see the reason for the downvote. This answers OP's question exactly (although an even better answer would be one which explains why `%` works like that).

Comment: @JohnColeman I didn't downvote but it *is* a quirk in `floor`. Why does `floor(1.9)` return 1 and `floor(1.9999)` return 1 but `floor(1.99999999999999999999)` return 2?

Comment: @Tagc probably that's because why https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Comment: @Tagc Try typing `1.99999999999999999999` at the prompt. `floor` is actually getting `2.0` as its argument, because `1.99999999999999999999` cannot be accurately represented as a floating-point value.

Comment: @Tagc if you look at  `math.frexp(-1e-16 % 2)` you will see that `-1e-16 % 2` *is* 2 -- not a float which is less than 2 which happens to be displayed as 2.

Comment: IMHO, the fact that -1e-16 % 2 returns 2.0 is not acceptable, even with all the good explanations that many people have given here. There could be at the very end of the % computation: if result == number-with-which-we-calculate-mod then result=0

Comment: Since computers does not have infinite storage and it stores floating point numbers as binary numbers it can not correct value of high precision values

Comment: @YvesSurrel you may refer to `sys.float_info.dig` for maximum number of decimal digits that can be faithfully represented in a float;   Even 1.1 + 2.2 =`3.3000000000000003` . You may use `Decimal`  package for exact calculations

Answer (score 2):

You're right that the result of `-1e-16` should not be `2.0`, but floats are weird, and infamously less than precise.  The specification of the `%` operator [states](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#id17):

> While abs(x%y) < abs(y) is true mathematically, for floats it may not be true numerically due to roundoff. For example, and assuming a platform on which a Python float is an IEEE 754 double-precision number, in order that -1e-100 % 1e100 have the same sign as 1e100, the computed result is -1e-100 + 1e100, which is numerically exactly equal to 1e100. The function math.fmod() returns a result whose sign matches the sign of the first argument instead, and so returns -1e-100 in this case. Which approach is more appropriate depends on the application.

Comment: I understand problems when we reach the ultimate limit of distinguishing 0.0 and not 0.0, i.e. when we are in the vicinity of  1.18 × 10−38, but 1e-16 is orders of magnitude above !

Comment: @YvesSurrel real numbers which are exactly representable by floats are not evenly distributed. Just because a given `x` near 0 is representable doesn't imply that `2 + x` is. `2 + -1e-16` evaluates to `2.0`.

Comment: Good point! It is true that (2.0 + 1e-16) - 2.0 is exactly 0.0