# In golang, how could I solve the issue by converting float to integer?

Tags: go, floating-point, type-conversion

There some codes about buckets sorting in golang.

However, I encounter a panic about index out of range [10] with length 10.

I find `bucketIdx := int((v - minValue) / bucketSize)` has some issues. Because `(v - minValue) / bucketSize` should be 9.9999999999. Howeverm, `int((v - minValue) / bucketSize)` would be 10. I am new learner in golang. I don't know how to solve it.

You can run these code here [demo](https://play.golang.com/p/Ay6XyRCLZYM)

This is the source code.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func bucketSort(array []float64) []float64 {
    // Determine minimum and maximum values
    minValue, maxValue := array[0], array[0]
    for _, v := range array {
        if v < minValue {
            minValue = v
        } else if v > maxValue {
            maxValue = v
        }
    }

    // Initialize buckets
    bucketSize := (maxValue - minValue) / 10
    bucketCount := 10
    buckets := make([][]float64, bucketCount)

    // Distribute elements into buckets
    for _, v := range array {
        bucketIdx := int((v - minValue) / bucketSize)
        buckets[bucketIdx] = append(buckets[bucketIdx], v)
    }

    // Sort buckets and place back into input array
    i := 0
    for _, bucket := range buckets {
        insertionSort(bucket)
        for _, v := range bucket {
            array[i] = v
            i++
        }
    }

    return array
}

func insertionSort(array []float64) {
    n := len(array)
    for i := 1; i < n; i++ {
        value := array[i]
        j := i - 1
        for j >= 0 && array[j] > value {
            array[j+1] = array[j]
            j--
        }
        array[j+1] = value
    }
}

func main() {
    array := []float64{0.897, 0.565, 0.656, 0.1234, 0.665, 0.3434}
    fmt.Println("Sorted Array: ", bucketSort(array))
}
```

Thanks for your time and consideration.

Actually, I have tried to use math.Floor() to solve the question. But it still doesn't run.

Comment: If you want to convert a floating point number to integer, consider using rounding as type conversion takes the integer part (truncates). Rounding: `int(f + 0.5)`. You can of course round to arbitrary unit, see [Golang Round to Nearest 0.05](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39544571/golang-round-to-nearest-0-05/39544897#39544897)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, actually, I don't want to use rounding as type conversion, I just want to truncate. 

If I use rounding, maybe it will cause a bigger index.

Comment: a  fix here would be to use `bucketSize := (maxValue  - minValue + 1) / 10` , to ensure that maxValue itself will still be at the last index.

Comment: Thank you, Sarath, your solution is good. But, I am still confused why int(9.9999999) would become 10.

Thank you again.

Comment: if     bucketSize := (maxValue - minValue) / 10 , (maxValue - minValue) / bucketSize would be 10 ( or more )


Btw,  floating point arithmetics could be tricky https://stackoverflow.com/a/41878360/1898494

Comment: @SarathSadasivanPillai Adding 1 makes sense if `maxValue, minValue` were integers.  Yet with floating point, adding 1 may be ineffective if `maxValue  - minValue` is huge or far too large if `maxValue  - minValue` is tiny.

Answer (score 3):

Mathematically, `bucketSize := (maxValue - minValue) / 10` , `(v - minValue) / bucketSize` generates the values [0...10].  (inclusive ends)

To generate the values [0...10) (note the `)` indicating non-inclusive), a different calculation is needed.

---

Given we are using floating point numbers, edge cases deserve consideration.  The [0...10] mentioned above may really be [a little less than 0 ... a little more than 10] given the finite precision of floating point math and its various rounding modes.

To avoid special edge case handling, rather than a `bucketSize` 1/10 the range, consider `1/(n-1)` or 1/9.  Then shift the index calculation by 0.5.

```
n = 10 - 1
bucketSize := (maxValue - minValue) / n
...
//               v-- about 0 to about 9.0 -v   
bucketIdx := int((v - minValue) / bucketSize + 0.5)
//               ^-- about 0.5 to about 9.5 -----^
//           ^------ 0 to 9 ----------------------^
```

It does make the end buckets half as populated, on average, than the middle buckets, yet we do not need a special edge test.

---

Of course you can go the the safe secure approach:

```
bucketSize := (maxValue - minValue) / 10
...
bucketIdx := int((v - minValue) / bucketSize)
if bucketIdx >= 10 {
  bucketIdx := 10-1
}
```

---

Additional considerations needed if any part of `(maxValue - minValue) / n` overflows or underflows.

Comment: Thanks, I learned a lot from your code. As for this question, you provide a good solution. However, I want to know more about how to truncate a floating number.

For example, I want to int(1.999999999999999999999999999) = 1, rather than 2

Thank you again

Comment: @Luke `float64` can exactly encode about 2^64 different values.  1.999999999999999999999999999 is **not** one of them.  Code takes that value, which is between 2 `float64` values: 1.9999999999999997779553950749686919152736663818359375 (0x1.fffffffffffffp+0) and 2.0 and selects the nearer one: 2.0.  `int(2.0)` is 2.

Comment: Instead of a large perturbation (multiplying bucketSize by 10/9), you may try a smaller perturbation (like multiplying bucketSize by 1.000001). This would introduce only a small amount of statistical bias...

Comment: @aka.nice That is a good idea.  Yet in the end, I prefer a solution that also well handles the `(maxValue - minValue) / n` over/underflow too - and that takes more thought.

Comment: @aka.nice Sorry, I don't know what you mean. My English is not good enough. Could you explain more clearly? Thank you.

Comment: @Luke What phrase is unclear?

Comment: I don't understand (multiplying bucketSize by 10/9) you're referring to. And what is the multiplying bucketSize by 1.0000001?

Comment: @Luke Consider `bucketSize := (maxValue - minValue) / 10;` then by slightly increasing it: (`bucketSize = bucketSize * 10 / 9` or `bucketSize = bucketSize * 1.0000001`, the following  `bucketIdx := int((v - minValue) / bucketSize)` will be in the range [0 ... 9].

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, Yes, I know it, but I feel confused that why and how you can ensure `bucketIdx  := int((v - minValue) / bucketSize)` will be in the range [0...9]. 

As for me, the solution is more clear
`bucketIdx := int((v - minValue) / bucketSize + 0.5)`


I wonder why both of you think multiplying bucket by 1.000001 is true and the way doesn't yield bugs.

Comment: @Luke With `bucketSize := (maxValue - minValue) / 10;` and without `bucketSize = bucketSize * 1.0000001`, `(v - minValue) / bucketSize` leads to 0.0 to 10.0. Agreed?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, I understand, thank you!